# Why are Ramza and Agrias "Gilgamesh Vanquishers"?

Tags: final-fantasy-tactics, final-fantasy-series, final-fantasy-brave-exvius

The upcoming banner for Final Fantasy Brave Exvius (global) is "Gilgamesh Vanquishers". Included in this banner are Ramza (FF Tactics), Agrias (FF Tactics), Snow (FF XIII), Exdeath (FF V), and Bartz (FF V).

After some [quick research](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gilgamesh), I see that Gilgamesh was Exdeath's right-hand man [in Final Fantasy V](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Gilgamesh_(Final_Fantasy_V)). Since Bartz is the main protagonist of FF V, his presence makes perfect sense. Exdeath might be a bit of a stretch as a "vanquisher", but I haven't played FF V so maybe that makes more sense than it appears.

I also see that Gilgamesh appears as a monster in FF XIII-2. It looks like [Snow](http://finalfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Snow_Villiers) at least makes an appearance in that sequel, so okay, maybe.

But why Agrias and Ramza? I've played FF Tactics dozens of times, and I don't remember Gilgamesh showing up, nor is that listed as one of his appearances on the wiki page.

It seems unlikely that this would be completely random, as there were plenty of other characters available for them to choose from that did vanquish Gilgamesh at some point, including a number from Final Fantasy Type-0 and Final Fantasy IV.

So, basically, what association is there between these characters and Gilgamesh? Does he appear in Final Fantasy Tactics?

Comment: Gilgamesh's appearance in XIII-2 was in a separate optional arena while Snow does appear in the plot and if i recall all the Arena fights were DLC. Gilgamesh's appearance in the Arena was similar to that of the appearance of Ultros and Typhoon from Final Fantasy VI, Jihl Nabaat, Amodar and Lightning (XIII) from Final Fantasy XIII in that the Arena appearances are inconsequential to the plot (since if i recall Jihl and Amodar died and Lightning is in Valhalla in that Etro Attie, not her Guardian Corp Uniform)

Comment: i also recall that V's Gilgamesh was banished to the Void but the Void connected to other Final Fantasy worlds as Gilgamesh appears in another Final Fantasy Game (not Dissidia) and confuses another character for being Bartz and fight them (i think XII? might even be XIII-2)

Comment: You're trying to find out reasoning to a series historically known for convoluted, twisted, and downright nonsensical decisions.  A series that isn't known for holding itself together between games, either.  I fail to see the utility in trying to find rationale in this.

Comment: I'm still debating whether to vote to close; I've played all those games, and I don't think there's any lore explanation for any of it.  This is just devs being devs because they want to make money.

Comment: @Frank If there's no connection at all, I'm okay with that as an answer, I'm just curious if there is one and I missed it. There are other characters from games that Gilgamesh *has* appeared in which would have been available for them to choose, so you would think there would be *some* reason they chose those two.

Comment: [*Comments Removed*] - We don't need the snark guys, let's be civil please. It is not a requirement that someone leave a comment when downvoting, and the main reason for this is the exact situation that unfolded here.

Comment: As for the question at hand: I've never played the games so I can't really say one way or the other what if any relationship the characters have, but the last sentence RE: whether Gilgamesh appears in FF:Tactics should be answerable. Building off that would be a good basis for an answer.

Comment: @Robotnik I don't know if there was another comment posted after I left yesterday, but I really wasn't offended by any of that. I just wanted to know if there was a problem with the post, and was satisfied with the explanation I received.

Comment: Hmm, I wonder if it's due to the weapon Excalibur that exists in FFT and was used by Gilgamesh in other FFs.